# How To find Child control Inside Page Resource?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, data-binding

We have a Windows phone application,  where we have DataTemplate inside Page.Resource. Below is the xaml :

```
    <PhoneApplicationPage
<PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<DataTemplate>
<ScrollViewer> // We want to fetch this control inside DataTemplate
..
</ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
</PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate={StatisSource DataTemplate}>
</ItemsControl>
</Grid>

</PhoneApplicationPage
```

So far we have used Visual Tree helper and iterate to find child control inside it. Below is the helper snippet we are using :

```
public T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            // If the child is not of the request child type child
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // child element found.
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

and calling above function as :

```
                ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChild<ScrollViewer>((this.View.FindName("AdSlider") as ItemsControl) ,"scrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
```

But scrollViewer object always have null value. We are unable to fetch expected control inside datatemplate. Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1 Don't provide a control name to your function**

Change :

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChild<ScrollViewer>((this.View.FindName("AdSlider") as ItemsControl) ,"scrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
```

I don't see any control named AdSlider in your sample.

Into :

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChild<ScrollViewer>((this.View.FindName("AdSlider") as ItemsControl) , null);
```

**2 provide a name to your DataTemplate**

Change :

```
<DataTemplate>
```

Into :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate1">
```

**3 Please also correct**

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate={StatisSource dataTemplate1}>
```

into:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate={StaticSource dataTemplate1}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Durin. But after doing all you suggested, FindChild method returns an exception 'reference is not a valid visual dependencyobject' because it wont accepting parameter as DataTemplate. So we tried another method as : ((this.View.FindName("AdvertSlider") as SlideViewExtended).ItemTemplate.LoadContent() as ScrollViewer). But this method create a same copy of UI elements and doesn't help us to manipulate scrolling behaviour of ScrollViewer.

Comment: I corrected some errors that seemed obvious to me. But after looking back I am not sure to understand what you re searching for. I also corrected point2 where code was not visible

Comment: We are trying to find scrollviewer inside datatemplate of Itemscontrol and our task is to scroll that scrollviewer after.

Comment: In what event  (Button.Click, ...) do you want to find the ScrollViewer ?

Comment: Thanks Durin for your feedback. But we somehow managed to scroll our scrollviewer by using attached properties. We did bind a attached vertical offset property found here : http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/07/21/exposing-and-binding-to-a-silverlight-scrollviewers-scrollbars.html